# How to convert a REAL32 to a Vector

Tags: java, stl

so I want to read a STL-File for a project and ran into the problem of not knowing how to read a REAL32 number and convert it to a useable Float Value.

TLDR how to read 12 byte REAL32 and convert it to 3 coordinates

(from Wikipedia)

```
foreach triangle                      - 50 bytes:
    REAL32[3] – Normal vector             - 12 bytes
    REAL32[3] – Vertex 1                  - 12 bytes
    REAL32[3] – Vertex 2                  - 12 bytes
    REAL32[3] – Vertex 3                  - 12 bytes
    UINT16    – Attribute byte count      -  2 bytes
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real32 is not 12 byte long. Each vertex has 3 real32 number, each one is for x, y and z coordinate respectively. Each coordinate is represented by 4 bytes that means 32 bit in little endian format, and that format is called real32.
You can write a function that converts 4 bytes real32 number to double.